# Robot Framework: How to avoid a variable value from being displayed in the console during execution

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I have the API Key to a server available in clear text in our tests.
To avoid this I came up with a new python script Secure.py (This includes 'encrypt' and 'decrypt' functions) and its working fine.

I have a decrypt keyword in my robot tests.

```
*** Variables ***
${secret_phrase}    abcdefghij        
${encrypted_Key}    ardfvbjgfrtavhdimdbshajakiugbn
```

I have used a secret phrase and the API key to encrypt and this is the encrypted key.

```
*** Test Cases ***
decrypt
  ${APIKEY}   Secure.Decrypt   ${secret_phrase}  ${encrypted_Key} 
  Should Not Be Empty   ${APIKEY}  shell=no
  Set Suite Variable   ${APIKEY}   shell=no
```

In this keyword I am passing in secret phrase and encrypted key so as a result I get the APIKEY.

#APIKEY result is printed in the Console, I don't want it to be printed in the console is there any way to do so?

Console:

```
${APIKEY}= asdfghjkl
```

Comment: The console, you mean the log.html file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Set Log Level](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Log%20Level) to disable all logging in your critical sections of the test case. This keyword will return the previous log level, which you could store in a variable and then you can use it later to restore the original log level.

> Sets the log threshold to the specified level and returns the old
> level.
>
> Messages below the level will not logged. The default logging level is
> INFO, but it can be overridden with the command line option
> `--loglevel`.
>
> The available levels: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO (default), WARN, ERROR and NONE (no logging).

An example:

```
*** Variables ***
${secret_phrase}    abcdefghij        
${encrypted_Key}    ardfvbjgfrtavhdimdbshajakiugbn


*** Test Case ***
decrypt
    ${old log level}=    Set Log Level    NONE    # disable logging
    ${APIKEY}   Set Variable    ${secret_phrase}_${encrypted_Key}
    Should Not Be Empty   ${APIKEY}
    Set Suite Variable   ${APIKEY}
    Set Log Level    ${old log level}    # enable logging
    ${public}=    Set Variable     This variable can be visible.
```

Here you can see the between the two `Set Log Level` call, nothing is logged, but after the original log level (`INFO`) has been restored logging is working again.

[image]